# On img click display a div

Tags: javascript, image, html

I'm trying to make a Javascript code that if you click on of the "cards" then a div will display above it.

Here is my current code but I can't figure out how to make it display more than just text. I would like to be able to display images or create shapes inside, etc.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = 'Hello';
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    });                     
    }
```

Here is my full code:

http://pastebin.com/ueqiywFu

I know my full code is not organized, many of my friends have told me. I am planning on organizing it after it is complete. Anyway please help me..

Comment: What you're writing is **JavaScript**, not jQuery.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for the correction. :) It's 5:30 AM here lol.

Comment: If you're planning to display complex things, you'd better code your structure directly in HTML, set it with `visibility:hidden;`, then use it as a template (and modify it if needed) wherever you need.

Comment: @Bigood True, but I would still have the problem of making the div visible after a card is clicked.

Comment: @FIFA14Packs Not a problem! Set its visibility back to normal after you cloned it, and appended it at the right place!

Answer (score 0):

Try **appending** elements to it:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = 'first div text';
var otherdiv = document.createElement('div');
otherdiv.innerHTML = 'second div text';
newdiv.appendChild(otherdiv);
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qcykL/3/)**

PS:
As **Terry** says, this is **Javascript,** not **JQuery.**  [This](http://jquery.com/) is JQuery.

Comment: Not working, thanks for the answer though. After I tried changing it to a div tag instead of a link it's not working. I would like to display a div not text. Here is my edited code: http://jsfiddle.net/qcykL/1/

Comment: @FIFA14Packs Use `setAttribute`

Comment: Alright I tried it, but I've never used setAttribute() before. This is my attempt though.http://jsfiddle.net/qcykL/2/

Comment: @FIFA14Packs Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qcykL/3/) fiddle, I appended a **div** *to* that **div.**